# Android Training - Source code missing?

Tags: android

Starting at http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

I selected the [ FIRST CLASS > ] button which takes me to
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html  . 
A page the explains the prerequisites for these lessons

- Download the Android SDK Starter Package.
- Install the ADT plugin for Eclipse (if you’ll use the Eclipse IDE).
- Download the latest SDK tools and platforms using the SDK Manager.

and a few other setup items, and then gives you an option of selecting
*[First Lesson]* or *[Creating an Android Project]* Both selections take you to
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Selecting *[Creating an Android Project]* takes you to a page that nicely walks
you threw the forms needed to create a blank project (No Code at this point)
and then give you an option to select *[next lesson]* -or- you can drop to the 
bottom of the page and select *[NEXT]* both choices take you to the same place 
"Running You App" (Still no code lines)

The first paragraph in Running Your App says
If you followed the *[previous lesson]* to create an Android project, it includes
a default set of "Hello World" source files that allow you to run the app right away.

```
- - -
```

I don't see any source code or files for "Hello World" in any of the training pages up to this point. Did I miss something? Dose the tutorial miss a step? I'm sure I can whip up a “hello world” program from scratch without any problems, but if I never played with Android before. This could easily be a show stopper for me. Is their some information missing from these lessons, or did I miss something?

Comment: Hello World make one activity in src folder itself

Comment: Where can i got the google android training source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They recently re-did their site and appear to have removed several lessons/tutorials that used to be there.  I haven't read anything to explain why (I would assume they feel they are out of date, not up to current standards) or if they would be back.